# Lua. Search string in a file and print second column

Tags: regex, lua

Looking for solution to replace following command in Lua:

```
grep "dhcp-range" /tmp/etc/dnsmasq.conf | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}'
```

tried

```
for line in file:lines() do
        if line:match("([^;]*),([^;]*),([^;]*),([^;]*),([^;]*)") then
                print(line[2])
        end
end
```

and it doesnt work.

/tmp/etc/dnsmasq.conf looks like this

```
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dhcp.leases
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto
addn-hosts=/tmp/hosts
conf-dir=/tmp/dnsmasq.d
stop-dns-rebind
rebind-localhost-ok
dhcp-broadcast=tag:needs-broadcast

dhcp-range=lan,192.168.34.165,192.168.34.179,255.255.255.0,12h
no-dhcp-interface=eth0
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `[^;]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `;` - why use it if your input has no semi-colons? What is the output you want to get in Lua?

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/s1U60B if you need to get `192.168.34.165`.

Comment: I want to get the line that starts with "dhcp-range" and print second and third value. Which is 192.168.34.165 and 192.168.34.179.

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/tFzZkZ will do?

Comment: @BJackson: I posted an answer with explanations, please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function in Lua that will print the values you need if you pass the whole file contents to it:

```
function getmatches(text)
    for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
        m,n = string.match(line,"^dhcp%-range[^,]*,([^,]+),([^,]+)")
        if m ~= nil then 
            print(m,n) 
        end
    end
end
```

See [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/sYN7ia)

With `string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+")`, each file line  is accessed (adjust as you see fit), and then the main part is `m,n = string.match(line,"^dhcp%-range[^,]*,([^,]+),([^,]+)")` that instantiates `m` with the first IP and `n` with the second IP found on a line that starts with `dhcp-range`.

**Lua pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `dhcp%-range` - a literal string `dhcp-range` (a `-` is a quantifier in Lua matching 0 or more occurrences, but as few as possible, and to match a literal `-`, it must be escaped. Regex escapes are formed with `%`.)
- `[^,]*,` - 0+ chars other than `,` and then a `,`
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1 (`m`): one or more chars other than `,`
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1 (`n`): one or more chars other than `,`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: How to get the last line from `file:lines()`, please help!

Comment: @Rainning Simply assign the `line` to a variable and at the end of the loop, just the last line value will be assigned to it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sorry for my unclearness. I meant: Is it possible to get the last line without the for-loop to speed up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for line in io.lines() do
    local a,b=line:match("^dhcp%-range=.-,(.-),(.-),")
    if a~=nil then
        print(a,b)
    end
end
```

The pattern reads: match `dhcp-range=` at the start of a line (note the need to escape `-` in Lua), skip everything until the next comma, and capture the next two fields between commas.