# Alternative of grep in lua script

Tags: lua

I have the following text file output.txt that I created (it has 15 colums including symbol `|` ):

```
[66] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:45:50.066928 | local_ip | 123.123.123.123 | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
[67] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:45:51.096955 | local_ip | 12.12.12.11 | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
[68] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:45:53.144942 | 123.123.123.123 | local_ip | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
[69] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:45:57.176956 | local_ip | 68.73.203.109 | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
[70] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:46:05.240953 | 123.123.123.123 | local_ip | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
[71] | alert:n | 3.0 | 10/22/2020-14:46:21.624979 | local_ip | 68.73.203.109 | United States of America | SURICATA STREAM ESTABLISHED SYNACK resend with different ACK
```

I'm familiar with the bash script, let say if I want to count total specific ip of `123.123.123.123` that can be found in the 9th column, I can implement like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
ip = "123.123.123.123"
report = output.txt
src_ip_count=$(grep "${ip}" "${report}" | awk '{ print $9 }' | grep -v "local_ip" | uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

and the output is:

```
[root@me lua-output]# ./test.sh
2
```

How do I implement the same code above in lua ? I know there is popen function can be used.. but is there a native way to do this in lua ? Also if I use popen, I also need to pass variable `$ip` and `$report` inside that command which I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua. Search string in a file and print second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619286/lua-search-string-in-a-file-and-print-second-column)

Comment: I have looked at that answer, it doesn't seems to help in my case. I need to understand if lua has native function that can read like grep do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to go about this, really. Assuming you read your data from stdin (though the same works for any file you manually open), you can do something like this:

```lua
local c = 0
for line in io.lines() do -- or or file:lines() if you have a different file
   if line:find("123.123.123.123") -- Only lines containing the IP we care about
      if (true) -- Whatever other conditions you want to apply
         c = c + 1
      end
   end
end
print(c)
```

Lua doesn't have a concept of what a "column" is, so you have to build that yourself as well. Either use a pattern to count spaces, or split the string into a table and index it.

Comment: I want to throw in the word Regex.

Comment: @stephanmg Lua does not have a builtin Regex module though, so that would require using a third-party module, which would be a bit overkill for this task.

Comment: Sorry, I meant pattern matching with Lua.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that if it is possible to use variable inside `popen` in lua. It is possible, and you can use grep command in lua.

So in lua you can do this:

```
-- lua script using grep example
ip = "123.123.123.123"
report = output.txt
local cmd = "grep -F " .. ip .. " " .. report .. " | awk '{ print $9 }' | grep -v 'local_ip' | uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }'"
local handle = io.popen(cmd)
local src_ip_count = handle:read("*a")
print(src_ip_count)
handle:close()
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer. It's working well but I prefer native lua code for this.

Comment: @KalibZen Yes, it's an alternative answer where you wonder in your question whether it's possible to include variable inside that popen function in lua.